# How to combine date and elapsed time into one datetime column in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I am trying to combine a date column and total elapsed time column into one datetime column.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
calendarid       actualdeparturetime   actualtriptime                       
2014-01-01       360.066667            26.716667
2014-01-01       384.050000            19.516667
2014-01-01       406.733333            21.900000
2014-01-01       424.850000            17.550000
2014-01-01       444.666667            23.100000
```

The actual departure time column is the total elapsed minutes in each day.
I would like to transform the dataframe to look like this:

```
actualdeparturetime   actualtriptime                       
2014-01-01 06:00:04   26.716667
2014-01-01 06:24:03   19.516667
2014-01-01 06:46:44   21.900000
2014-01-01 07:04:51   17.550000
2014-01-01 07:24:40   23.100000
```

I've tried several techniques including timedelta and using a csv data parser, however i am still learning and can't seem to solve this on my own. Can anyone help please?

My ultimate goal is to aggregate the data into 30 minute intervals for each day  then take the mean of the actual trip time in each interval. I am under the assumption converting to a datetimeindex i can resample the data under those assumptions. However, if there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `astype("timedelta64[m]")`

```
In [608]: df['calendarid'] + df['actualdeparturetime'].astype("timedelta64[m]")
Out[608]:
0   2014-01-01 06:00:00
1   2014-01-01 06:24:00
2   2014-01-01 06:46:00
3   2014-01-01 07:04:00
4   2014-01-01 07:24:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple addition along with [`pandas.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert `calenderid` column to datetime, and [`pandas.to_timedelta()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to convert `actualdeparturetime` column to timedelta (along with `unit='m'` argument to take units as minutes). Example -

```
df['actualdeparturetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calendarid']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['actualdeparturetime'],unit='m')
```

Demo -

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   calendarid  actualdeparturetime  actualtriptime
0  2014-01-01           360.066667       26.716667
1  2014-01-01           384.050000       19.516667
2  2014-01-01           406.733333       21.900000
3  2014-01-01           424.850000       17.550000
4  2014-01-01           444.666667       23.100000

In [38]: df['actualdeparturetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calendarid']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['actualdeparturetime'],unit='m')

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
   calendarid        actualdeparturetime  actualtriptime
0  2014-01-01 2014-01-01 06:00:04.000020       26.716667
1  2014-01-01 2014-01-01 06:24:03.000000       19.516667
2  2014-01-01 2014-01-01 06:46:43.999980       21.900000
3  2014-01-01 2014-01-01 07:04:51.000000       17.550000
4  2014-01-01 2014-01-01 07:24:40.000020       23.100000
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with combining datetime and timedelta values. This clears things up.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful! :-) . Also If the answers were helpful , I would like to request you to accept any answer (whichever you think is the best/most helpful) by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of the answer , it would be helpful for the community